# Which powerfull tools are used to create website and could GWT and GXT work ?

Tags: javascript, css, html, gwt, gxt

So I started working this year after finished studying last year. I have been exposed to so many things in the working environment. Suck as Maven, GWT and Hibernate. 
Now I got this side project in which I just need to create a simple website which would bassically just display some information and contacting details. 
So I was wondering if HTML5 CSS and JavaScript is still the way to go and if there are not powerfull frameworks in which could you help me do animations and graphics much easier. 
Also if you know GWT and GXT would it be a bad idea to create a visually apealing website using these frameworks.

Thank you so much for reading
Have a nice day

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective: Create a simple website which would basically just display some information and contacting details.

**GXT:** 
GXT is built on GWT.
Go for GXT when you are in need of rich set of widgets (it is a very large set of collection) out of the box. Have a look on the following link where GXT has showcased the different widgets
http://examples.sencha.com/gxt/4.0.0/

**GWT:**
GWT will be having minimal set of widgets when compared to GXT. Have a look on the different widgets which are provided out of the box. http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html

**Javascript Animation framework:**
There are bunch of javascript libraries/frameworks for animation, choose one which is most appropriate to your work. Have a look on the following link.
https://www.javascripting.com/animation/

**Conclusion:**
Consider the following before finalizing on a framework

1. Framework which is having more out of the box components which matches the requirement.
2. Framework which is more stable
3. Framework which is having more support on the internet, such as forums, blogs.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Would I be able to combine GWT and the Javascript animation framework since GWT is coded in Java

Comment: Yes you can, I had tasted success when using highcharts js together with GWT.